# Uploading Difficulties to Discountasp.net, new at C#

Tags: .net, sql-server, file-upload, hosting, discountasp

I've been trying to upload a new page to a site hosted on a DiscountASPnet server, but have been having trouble. I have been working on this site in the development server for a while now. it was already built and hosted when I got my hands on it, and I haven't worked in ASP.net before. First I uploaded the page itself, the code behind, the designer file, and the sitemap in FileZilla. It gave me a parse error when I tried to navigate to the new page so I decided to upload the website in its entirety since it works properly on the VS development server, when I did that the entire site stopped working and wouldn't load any pages. Now I am trying to publish the entire site in Visual Studio using Web Deploy but I am recieving an error message with that too: "... an existing connection was forcible closed by the remote host" I'm just trying to upload one page to the website. I didn't think it would be so hard. If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try posting your question on their [community forum](http://community.discountasp.net/) since this sounds like a particular issue with discountasp.net and they might be better able to assist you.